# How do I use new to create an array with a non-default constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

```
class Base{
public:
    Base() = default;
    Base(int a_, int b_):a(a_),b(b_){}
    int a;    
    int b;
};

Base *object = new Base(1,2); // works
Base *object2 = new Base(1,2)[10]; // error
Base *object3 = new Base[10](1,2); // error
```

I want to create an array of Base objects that are initialized using {1,2} but the last two lines of the above code doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: [You can use placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754763/c-object-array-initialization-without-default-constructor), but **why don't you use a vector,** in first place?

Comment: @gmas80 that's an entirely different problem.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343558/how-do-i-declare-an-array-of-objects-whose-class-has-no-default-constructor