# C++ dynamic allocation of class array

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation

Assume a `class X` with a constructor function `X(int a, int b)`

I create a pointer to X as `X *ptr;` to allocate memory dynamically for the class.

Now to create an array of object of class X

```
 ptr = new X[sizeOfArray];
```

until now everything is fine. But what I want to do is creation of the above array of objects should invoke the constructor function `X(int a, int b)`. I tried as follows:

```
ptr = new X(1,2)[sizeOfArray];
```

As expected It gave me compile time error

> error: expected ';' before '[' token|

How can I create an array of objects to invoke the constructor?

`SizeOfArray` is entered by the user at runtime.

**EDIT:**
What I wanted to achieve in not possible as answered by zenith or will be too complex . So how can I use `std::vector` for the same?

Comment: Why not `std::vector`?

Comment: School Assignment..Can't use STL.

Comment: For the Edit: `std::vector<X> xs(sizeOfArray, X(1, 2));`

Comment: @Pushkar: If you want to ask for clarification on zenith's answer, please do so in a comment to his answer. That said, ^Jarod42's comment is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a job for [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new)...

Here's a basic example:

<kbd>[**Run It Online !**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96bcecacbd7e1822)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>  // size_t
#include <new>      // placement new

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct X
{
    X(int a_, int b_) : a{a_}, b{b_} {}
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    const size_t element_size   = sizeof(X);
    const size_t element_count  = 10;

    // memory where new objects are going to be placed
    char* memory = new char[element_count * element_size];

    // next insertion index
    size_t insertion_index = 0;

    // construct a new X in the address (place + insertion_index)
    void* place = memory + insertion_index;
    X* x = new(place) X(1, 2);
    // advance the insertion index
    insertion_index += element_size;

    // check out the new object
    cout << "x(" << x->a << ", " << x->b << ")" << endl;

    // explicit object destruction
    x->~X();

    // free the memory
    delete[] memory;
}
```

**EDIT**: If I've understood your edit, you want to do something like this:

<kbd>[**Run It Online !**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67e2e0624cf5b1ff)</kbd>

```
#include <vector>
// init a vector of `element_count x X(1, 2)`
std::vector<X> vec(element_count, X(1, 2));

// you can still get a raw pointer to the array as such
X* ptr1 = &vec[0];
X* ptr2 = vec.data();  // C++11
```

Comment: `std::aligned_storage` may help. But `std::vector` is simpler.

Comment: `std::aligned_storage` is certainly interesting. As of `std::vector`, the OP is required not to use it. Besides, I think [`std::vector` does use placement new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax#Default_placement).

Comment: see edit. I might try `std::vector` since this seems too complex to follow

Comment: I am allocating the memory by a setter function the class. Will the data remain in memory after the function returns?

Comment: @OP unless you provide actual code snippets for what you did, I'm afraid that I won't be able to give you a relevant answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in the current C++ standard, unless:

- you provide an initializer for each element, or
- you use a `vector`.

See:

- [Object array initialization without default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4754763/3425536)
- [How do I declare an array of objects whose class has no default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2343558/3425536)

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if `sizeOfArray` is a variable or a constant. If it is a (small) constant, you can do this in C++11:

```
X* ptr = new X[3] { {1,2}, {1,2}, {1,2} };
```

Comment: `SizeOfArray` is entered by the user at runtime