# Arduino C++ Declare array of objects with parameters in constructor

Tags: c++, arduino

I only want to declare an array of objects of class `control` with size of 5. The contents of the specific objects will be filled afterwards.

```
class control {
  public:
    control(char* controlName) {
    name = controlName;
  }

  private:
  char* name;
};

void setup() {
  control humidityControl("humidityControl");
  // Problem: Declare an array controlArray with the size of 5 and the name "controlArray"
  control controlArray[5]("controlArray"); // Error: no matching function for call to 'control::control()'
  control controlArray("controlArray")[5]; // Error: expected ',' or ';' before '[' token
}


void loop() {

}
```

I'm using C++ on my Arduino. I'd appreciate every tipp how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Also relevant: [How do I declare an array of objects whose class has no default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2343558/580083).

Comment: No, because as I I know there's no library `vector` for Arduino.

Comment: Have you seen this question: [Vectors in Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9986591/580083)?

Comment: BTW, are you aware that by assigning pointers you don't copy data they are pointing to?

Comment: I haven't seen that question, that's great, thanks! Just for information: Is there a way to fix this without this library? And: Actually I wanted to copy the name with class control {
  public:
    control(char controlName[10]) {
    name[10] = controlName; // This works
    name = controlName; // This doesn't -> why?
  }

  private:
  char name[10];
};``

Comment: Yes, in the second question I linked, see the second answer.

Comment: Because you cannot copy c-strings just by assigning pointers/arrays. You need to use `strcpy` or similar functions.

Comment: Well, but that only works if I declare and define it in one step AND I know the contents when I define it. But I don't know that yet, it will be filled during runtime. Or did I misunderstood the answer...?

Comment: Then, generally, you can hardly avoid dynamic memory allocations. If you don't know the numbers in advance, there is basically no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're mixing the declaration of an array (the square brackets) with a call to the constructor. This SO answer clarifies it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598409/2881667.

What you want to do is this:

```
void setup() {
  control controlArray[5] = {"controlArray", "controlArray", "controlArray", "controlArray", "controlArray"};
}
```

Notice how you have to include the argument to the constructor 5 times. To avoid that, you have two options:

1. Use a default constructor:

```
control(char* controlName = "controlArray");
```

Might work for you, but only if you plan on initializing all arrays with the same value.

2. If using `gcc`, you can use its extension to initialize it like this:

```
control controlArray[5] = {[0 ... 4] = "controlArray"};
```

But this will only work with `gcc`, so not so good for portability.

Also, unrelated to your question - I think you probably meant to copy the string, and not store the pointer in your class, so you should use something like `strncpy` in the constructor, instead of just assigning to `name`, and you'll have to preallocate storage for `name` in that case (either declare it as a char array, like `char name[255];`, allocate space for it in the constructor, or use `std::string` to make it all easier).

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestions don't work for me (the name differ). About your string suggestion: I tried that
`class control {
  public:
    control(char controlName[10]) {
    name = controlName; // Throws error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [10]'
  }

  private:
  char name[10];
  //char* name;
};

void setup() {
  control humidityControl("humidityControl");
}


void loop() {
  
}`

but it doesn't work... I'd rather copy the value than pointing to it. But why doesn't that work?

Comment: The source (the argument `controlName`) should remain a `char *`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it - I tried the `*` at all possible places but it doesn't work...